# TclOO: How to forward to variables?

Tags: oop, tcl

I have learned that I can `forward` commands to objects that where created in the constructor. As far as I understand it these objects exist as commands in the instance namespace. 
But what do I do if the object I want to forward to has been passed to the constructor as an argument from outside instead of being created inside the constructor? 
Storing it as a variable does not work, because `forward` works only with commands. I have thought of using `interp alias` to create a 'local' command that I can forward to, but I'll have to admit that the whole notion of commands vs variables still feels somewhat cumbersome to me (I'm more used to Python or C#).

For illustration see the following example:

```
oo::class A {
  method hello {} {
    puts "Hello, from [self]"
  }
}

oo::class B {
  constructor {some_a3} {
    A create a1
    A create a2

    # store some_a3
    variable a3
    set a3 $some_a3
    # this won't work because forward works on commands not variables
  }
  forward var1 a1
  forward var2 a2
  forward var3 ???
}
```

so that it can be used like this:

```
set a3 [A new]
set b [B new $a3]
$b var1 hello
$b var2 hello
$b var3 hello
```

PS: Should my approach be totally off course (un-TCL like) I'm willing to listen to alternative suggestions. :)

Comment: Tcl's commands are _completely_ distinct from its variables. That cross-over that exists is with lambda applications via the `apply` command, but that's quite syntactically different. We know about this, and we're contemplating the steps to narrow the gap (but not close it entirely; we _like_ to distinguish name from use). A deeper discussion of this is rather too long for a comment field, and would be hard to fit into being on topic for a full answer…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can't* forward to a variable directly; the forwarding mechanism is pretty straight-forward. But you *can* create the forwarding in the constructor. This is done with the `oo::objdefine` command, which makes per-instance changes to the object, almost as if you were changing the most-specific subclass (except it's not a class at all; it really is the instance).

```
oo::class B {
    constructor {some_a3} {
        A create a1
        A create a2
        ##### The next line does the magic #####
        oo::objdefine [self]  forward var3  $some_a3
        # The double-spaces are for clarity only; they separate the part that belongs
        # to the call to the defining command, the forwarded method declaration, and
        # what it is being forwarded to. Two spaces is as good as one in Tcl command
        # invocations...
    }
    forward var1  a1
    forward var2  a2
}
```

In this case, the object passed in won't be *owned* by the instance of `B`; you'll have to delete it manually. Also, you'll probably want to make sure that the command name is fully-qualified. TclOO by default returns objects as fully-qualified names, but most other Tcl commands are usually not qualified (e.g., almost all of them in both your script and mine).

Comment: Thanks. To pick up your point about manually deleting the instance: How would I do that? I would presume with 'my var3 destroy' called for example in the destructor of B, is that correct?

Comment: Manually deleting the instance would be `$a3 destroy`. If you want to do that in the destructor of `B`, that's when you _should_ keep it in a variable. But building the child instance inside the constructor when that ownership relationship exists is simpler.

Comment: My question was only for clarification. I'm working on a tree like structure and am trying to handle references from child to parent (the ownership goes the other way, from parent to child). On that note: how would you handle children that are added dynamically (that is, not while the parent is constructed)?

Comment: You can use `oo::objdefine` (or even `oo::define`) at _any time you want;_ the constructor isn't really very special there, and you can keep the collection of objects in an instance variable easily enough. The main thing to note is that if you're handling many children, you probably won't want to expose each as its own forwarded method. (Not sure how to do it as such; the answer depends on the real details, not the hypothetical ones of your sample.) For example, you might instead think in terms of “forwarding” some methods to _all_ children (with a helper method?)

Comment: You _might_ even be able to use `oo::objdefine` in the destructor, but I wouldn't recommend it (it'd be entirely pointless, in fact!)